# Password strenght

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an assignment for my class, and even when I try everything, something seems to go wrong with my code. I'm supposed to make a tiny program that would check the strength of one's password. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Much appreciated.

```
p = raw_input("Enter password") if len(p) <= 6:
    print("Weak1") elif len(p) > 6 and len(p) <=12:
    if p.lower:
        print("Weak2")
    elif p.upper() or int():
        print("Medium4") elif len(p) > 12:
    if p.lower and not p.upper():
        print("Strong6")
    elif p.upper() and p.lower():
        print("Strong7")
    elif int() and p.lower():
        print("Strong9")
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code first?

Comment: What's the difference between `p.lower` and `p.lower()`?

Comment: See the documentation for [**`str.lower()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower). Strings in Python are immutable, meaning you can't change them. It returns a new string, in lower case. Are you wanting to check whether the whole string is lowercase? Or digits? etc.

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of problems in your syntax. after reformatting your code,
consider these builtin methods. [full list here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

```
>>> password = "mylowercasepassword"
>>> password.islower()
True
>>> password2 = "MYSPRPSSWRD"
>>> password2.islower()
False
>>> password2.isupper()
True
>>> pwd = "MySvp3rStr0ngpw4"
>>> pwd.isalpha()
False
>>> pwd.isalnum()
True
```

Instead of using `p.lower()`, `p.upper()` and etc, which always will evaluate `true`, use the methods shown below.

You can rewrite your code such that, but try to understand more genuine solutions. Btw, I've fixed some parts of your code.

```
p = raw_input("Enter password")

if len(p) <=6: 
# abCd1, Psw44 etc.
    print "Your password is weak"
elif len(p) >6 and len(p)<=12:
## Password, pAssphrase etc.
    if p.islower():
    #password, passphrase   
        print "Length is ok, but you should use mixed case or whatever else"
    elif p.isupper() or p.isdigit():
    #PASSWORD, PASSPHRASE (is upper), 712356433 (is digit)  
        print "Another warning message"
    #other elifs and else
elif len(p)>12:
#l0ngPasswordjumped0v3r1azyrabbit   
    if p.isalpha() or p.isalnum():
    #myReallyLongPassword (is alpha), l0ngPasswordjumped0v3r1azyrabbit (is alnum)   
        print "Really strong"
    elif (not p.islower()) and (not p.isuppper()) and (not p.isdigit()):
    #ParaPsychOlOGY (is not lower, is not upper, and is not digit)  
        print "Another strong"
    #other elifs and else
#other conditional
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is that you are inventing your own password strength estimator which is not based on the best principles and research, but your own invented rules :)

There [exist a Python library zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/python-zxcvbn), which gives more realistic password strength estimations.

Please note that this is probably not answer what you want, but the answer what you would do if you would be building a real, secure, service.

Comment: While your answer is absolutely correct, this is a homework assignment where the OP is supposed to learn how to handle strings. I think they are supposed to check the password based on a small set of rules.

Comment: @idjaw: Yes, Thanks. I noticed that and added a disclaimer at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `re` module to find if String contains both uppercase and lowercase, How many uppercase and lowercase, etc..
Here is a simple implementation I did.
It's still a Fool script! But still works!

```
import sys, os
try:
    import re
except:
    os.system("python -m pip install re")
    import re
try :
    import string
except:
    os.system("python -m pip install string")
    import string


password = (raw_input("Type the Password : "))
p = password
strength = []

def AnalyzePassword():
    total = 0
    for k in strength:
        total = total + int(k)

    total_analyze = int(total) + 0.0
    analyzed = int( (total_analyze) * 10)
    analyzed = str(analyzed).replace("00", "0")
    result = analyzed
    return result




def PassLvlChecker(passd):
    if len(passd) <  18:    strength.append("-4")
    elif len(passd) > 18:   strength.append("4")
    if passd.isalpha():     strength.append("2")
    if bool(re.compile('[\W]+').findall(passd)) is True:    strength.append("7")
    if bool(re.compile("[A-Z]+").findall(passd)) is True:   strength.append("5")
    if bool(re.compile("[0-9]+").findall(passd)) is True:   strength.append("9")

    if len(passd) > 18 and \
    bool(re.compile('[\W]+').findall(passd)) is True and\
    bool(re.compile("[A-Z]+").findall(passd)) is True and\
    bool(re.compile("[0-9]+").findall(passd)) is True:
        strength.append("15")

    strength.append(str(len(passd)))

    return AnalyzePassword()





def checkAgain(pas):
    if pas == '':
        p = raw_input("Type the Password : ")
        checkAgain(p)
    else:
        passStrength = PassLvlChecker(password)
                print "Your password is", str((int(passStrength))) + "%", "Secured!"

if p == '':
    p = (raw_input("Type the Password : "))
    checkAgain(p)
else:
    passStrength = PassLvlChecker(password)
    print "Your password is", str((int(passStrength))) + "%", "Secured!"
```